# Root relative document URL in Viewer load failing

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've been going through the example of Augusto's to enable a model to be loaded offline ([https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-airplane-mode]) and have run into an issue around specifying the document path, I can't set a root-relative path for my assets.

Using an absolute URL works but isn't practical/best practice in a javascript file (caching, domain/asset paths changing etc)

I've tried a single / and a double // but the path is still calculated as ./(AssetPath)

Is there a way to force this to load or will I have to rewrite the load methods to pass in an absolute URL to load the asset from?

Adapted from the listed example:

```
var myViewerDiv = document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv');
var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(myViewerDiv);
var options = {
    'env': 'Local',
    'document': '/Assets/1/1/0.svf'
};
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function () {
        viewer.start(options.document, options);
});
```

This does not load the document from **"/Assets/1/1/0.svf"** but instead from **"../Assets/1/1/0.svf"**.

**Expected Document Request for below: "http://localhost:port/Assets/1/1/0.svf"**

Page Path: "/Model/"
Actual Document Request: "http://localhost:port//Assets/1/1/0.svf"

Page Path: "/Model/Packs/"
Actual Document Request: "http://localhost:port/Model/Assets/1/1/0.svf"

Given I set a route-relative URL I think it should be "/Shaver/0.svf" for the second example also

From some investigation I think the issues are in viewer3d.js `Document.getDocumentPath` and `avp.pathToURL` methods

Comment: I don't really understand your question... be more precise and show us what you are trying to do please (concrete code sample not just abstract description) - Thanks

Comment: Thanks Philippe, I've updated with the code I'm using, the requests and what I think is the expected response  

I'll save my other question around loading differences on Viewer vs ViewingApplication and extensions for a separate question

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any problem on my side, did you try `Assets/1/1/0.svf`?

Typically I have a route exposed by server `/resources` which points to a directory containing static resources (files, images, svf and so on ...). The directory itself could be located anywhere and named whatever as long as the server maps it to `/resources`, then the path I am providing to the viewer is as follow:

```
 viewer.start()
 viewer.loadModel('resources/models/dev/office/Resource/3D_View/3D/office.svf')
```

You may take a look at this article for more details:

[Working seamlessly online/offline when developing your Web applications with the Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/10/working-seamlessly-onlineoffline-when-developing-apps-with-the-forge-viewer-.html)

Hope that helps

Comment: I have the same (mine is called Assets) that contains the manifest, the svf, the pf files etc. Using the example there I get a result in the comments of https://jsfiddle.net/dLyuLhun/

Comment: Can you copy the page you are using and put it into a subfolder and see if the content still loads the same. I see the same issue on 2.16 and 2.17 of the viewer3d.js file

Comment: I'm not sure what the jsfiddle is supposed to demonstrate and I don't understand what you mean in the 2nd comment as well :s ... did you modify the directory structure of the svf resource and how did you extract it? You can take a look here if that helps: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs. I can load SVF offline and remotely hosted on my own server fine, so you must do something wrong ...

Comment: The jsfiddle shows the external js file and where the failing request is made to. I have 2 pages "/Model/" and "/Model/Pack". Referencing the same js file to do the load (the jsfiddle) "/Model/" loads successfully, but the "/Model/Pack/" url tries to load assets from "/Model/Assets/1/1/". This is not an issue of it not working 100% of the time. The issue is the generation of the URL is incorrect when specifying a route relative URL http://ifyoucodeittheywill.com/2009/03/absolute-relative-and-root-relative-urls/